# Is an infinite amount of heat is produced in an L-R circuit?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

Consider a simple L-R circuit. When I tried to find heat generated in an L-R circuit, I got the result as, mathematically speaking, **the work done by the battery, and the heat produced in the resistor are infinite till steady state is reached.**

The integral I used for Voltage energy is
$$∫VIdt,$$
where $V$ is the constant voltage and $I$ is
$$I=V/R(1 - e^{-Rt/L}),$$
from $t=0$ to $t=\infty$.

---

Is this true?  Please explain this with reference to both ideal and real case.

Comment: Of course it's not true. At most there will be an instantaneous infinite _power_ in some case, but this does not happen in even an ideal, conventional L-R circuit – unless you actually mean some transient scenario. The question is very unclear.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sir I have updated my question to show what exactly do I mean.Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: these circuit used to draw minimum heat from the circuit so if you want to get the het produced do it for half cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this true? Please explain this with reference to both ideal and real case.

Yes, this is true. An ideal RL circuit running for an infinite amount of time will require an infinite amount of energy which will primarily go to heat in the resistor.

For the real case, of course, the battery has a finite amount of energy and as it drains the voltage goes to zero. When the voltage is zero then the current is also zero and no further energy is dissipated by the resistor. The total energy is then finite.

Answer (score 3):

In, essence, an LR circuit is a battery connected to a resistor with some wire which is looped around enough that it experiences inductive magnetic effects when the current through it changes.

However, as you approach the steady state, the inductive part of the circuit becomes less and less relevant, and you're basically describing a battery hooked up to a resistor, which will tend to dissipate constant power.

You are effectively integrating this constant power between time $t=0$ and the $t\to\infty$ limit. It should be no surprise that you get an infinite answer.

Of course, over any *finite* duration, the energy dissipated will be finite.